# Webmatrix recognises the wrong "}"

Tags: razor, webmatrix

My page consists of the following code:

```
@{
var db= Database.Open("Surgestuff");
var sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM Comments";
var data = db.Query(sqlQ);
Page.Title = "Add Comment"; 
}
@{
    var CommenterrorMessage = "";
    var LengtherrorMessage = "";
    var date = @DateTime.Now;
        if (IsPost) {
        var CommName = "";
        var Comment = "";
        CommName=Request["formName"];
        Comment=Request["formComm"];
        var Dt = @DateTime.Now;
        var isValid = true;
        if (Comment.IsEmpty()){
            CommenterrorMessage = "This field is required";
            isValid = false;
        }

        else if (Comment.Length > 400){
            LengtherrorMessage = "Comment must be less than 400 characters";
            isValid = false;
        }

        else if (CommName.IsEmpty()){
            CommName = "Anonymous";
        }

        if (isValid){
        var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO Comments (Name, Comment, Dt) " + "VALUES (@0, @1, @2)";
        db.Execute(SQLINSERT, CommName, Comment, Dt);
        Response.Redirect("~/Comments");
        }

        else
        {
            <p class="message error">Please correct the errors and resubmit the form.</P> 
        }
    }
}
<fieldset><legend>Add Comment</legend>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Name:
  <p><input type="text" id="Name" name="formName"/></p>
  Comment:
  <p><textarea cols="35" rows="5" id="Comment" name="formComm"/></textarea></p>
     @if(!CommenterrorMessage.IsEmpty()) {
        <label for="formComm" class="validation-error">
            @CommenterrorMessage
        </label>
    }
     @if(!LengtherrorMessage.IsEmpty()) {
        <label for="formComm" class="validation-error">
            @LengtherrorMessage
        </label>
    }

  <p><input type="submit" value="Add Comment" /></p>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

And when i try to run this page it gives me the error:

' "2" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid. '
When i look at the files workspace in webmatrix it recognises the first closing "}" as the end for the whole code block then disregards the rest until it gets to "@2". I have had the exact same code working on my website before i upgraded to webmatrix 2.0. How can i fix this?

Comment: (Why did we go back to code-in-markup anyway? :-/)

Comment: I gave as much information as possible to hopefully receive an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally copy/pasted your code into WebMatrix (on my Virtual Box). You have 2 `@DateTime.Now`s inside your Razor `@{ ... }` code. if you change them to:

```
... = DateTime.Now;
```

it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Razor, anywhere you need to use @ as itself (not Razor indicator), use: `@@`.

So Try: `@@0, @@1, @@2`.

Source: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: Ok. I'm not very familiar with WebMatrix. Is there any `\bin` folder in the project directory? try to remove application `.dll` files from `\bin` and rebuild the application.

Comment: There is a /bin folder but with WebMatrix you can't just delete them and rebuild the application, if I do that it gives me file dependency errors because it doesn't automatically retrieve them. I have changed my validation to the preferred format for WebMatrix and taken a screenshot to show how WebMatrix disregards sections of code [Screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/48386169/inconsiderate.png)

Comment: I think I finally found it, posted a new answer.